# Why there is an 'el' before the title in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, artículos

In English we usually call somebody 'Mr...' to show our respect to the person. However, I find that in Spanish the usage is quite different: an *el* is needed before the title *señor*.

For example, *Mr White*, when translated into Spanish is *el señor White* (the Mr. White). Why there is an *el* before the title in Spanish?

Comment: Note that this is only when referring to someone in third person: _El señor Blanco no vendrá hoy._ When addressing directly to that person, the article is not needed: _Señor Blanco, ¿va a venir hoy?_ By the way, welcome to [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo by the way, also this is the post number 20000 in [spanish.se] history!! 4K questions, 20K posts, that's quite a lot in 5 years :)

Answer (score 1):

*Señor* is a word that has several meanings. The meaning you refer to (the supposed translation of "Mister", I'll come back to this later) is just the 9th one:

> **[señor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcBNzxH)**
>
> 9. m. y f. U. como término de cortesía con que dirigirse a una persona o mencionarla anteponiéndolo a su apellido, o bien al nombre y apellido precedidos de *don* o de *doña*, o al cargo que desempeña. *Señor González. Señora doña Luisa Pérez. Señora presidenta.*

Translated: it is used as a courtesy before someone's surname, o before the whole name preceded by *don* or *doña*. And that's the trick: "Mister" is gramatically equivalent to "don". When using *don* you do not need an article:

> Don Alfonso no vendrá esta noche.

That's because *[don](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E7fKGDe)* is just a courtesy title. The English gramatical equivalent to "señor" would be "lord". Note the first and main meaning of *señor*:

> 1. m. y f. Persona que gobierna en un ámbito determinado. *La señora de la casa.*

Translated: person who governs in a particular area. You have an example in one of the most famous books: "The Lord of the Rings" is translated into Spanish as "El Señor de los Anillos". Note the use of the article in both languages. The use of *señor* with this meaning kind of *collides* with the use as a courtesy title, hence the use of the article is kept when referring to someone using *señor* in third person: saying "el señor González" is gramatically the same as saying "el señor de estas tierras".

Comment: Note also the parallels with Portuguese *senhor* and with French *monsieur*; the former takes an article, as in Spanish and for the same reason, while the latter does not because it means "my lord", i. e. it's already determined by the possessive.

Answer (score 0):

En lo general y amplio del lenguaje:
No es siempre correcto usar un artículo antes de un nombre, adjetivo o sustantivo. En Chile, por ejemplo, es habitual decir:

> La María está comiendo en la mesa.

Cuando lo correcto sería decir:

> María está comiendo en la mesa.

Pero pueden haber excepciones informales para el ejemplo que preguntas:

**Decir "El señor White", hace referencia a hablar de él en tercera persona con un tercero**. Primero articulo el adjetivo "señor", para separar el adjetivo de posibles confusiones. 
Por ejemplo, si digo, "señor de la casa", la frase completa se podría entender como un adjetivo (entiéndase ésto como español culto informal). Pero, si digo "el señor de la casa", solo se tomaría como adjetivo "señor" y "casa" como sustantivo.

Agregar también que en la tradición latinoamericana informal del español hablado, decir "Señor" en español solo debe ser usado cuando se menciona el apellido del sujeto. Cuando se usa el nombre se debe usar el "Don".

Don es una abreviación de "domĭnus" (Latín), perteneciente al español ibérico medieval renacentista. Su traducción al español actual es: propietario o señor. Si bien pueden parecer sinónimos hoy día entre "señor" y "don", cierto es que no se usan indistintamente, y tienen una aplicación informal muy acotada y conocida.

En el caso de las mujeres con la palabra "señor", sirve para identificar estado civil de la mujer. Señorita es usado solo para niñas y mujeres solteras, mientras que, señora, solo para casadas o mujeres de edad mayor.

Finalmente,para efectos informales y hasta coloquiales, el artículo "el" (nunca confundir con el pronombre personal "él") ayuda antes de la frase "Señor White" durante la conversación de terceros sobre White sin él presente.